# Segmentation fault 11 - Bridging-header

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm getting an issue when trying to archive my project. Everything works fine when running on a device, simulator or running unit tests, but when I try to archive it I get the `Segmentation fault 11` error. Among other things, the standout segment of the error seems to be:

```
/Users/[USER]/Projects/[PROJECT]/[PROJECT]-ios/[PROJECT]/[PROJECT]-Bridging-Header.h:15:9: error: 'Mixpanel.h' file not found
#import "Mixpanel.h"
        ^
0  swift                    0x00000001033e84eb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 43
1  swift                    0x00000001033e77d6 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 70
2  swift                    0x00000001033e8b4f SignalHandler(int) + 287
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff84e9252a _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007f9ffc822bf0 _sigtramp + 2006517472
5  swift                    0x0000000101604397 swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::addEntryToLookupTable(clang::Sema&, swift::SwiftLookupTable&, clang::NamedDecl*) + 151
6  swift                    0x0000000101604462 swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::addEntryToLookupTable(clang::Sema&, swift::SwiftLookupTable&, clang::NamedDecl*) + 354
7  swift                    0x0000000101604ec9 swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::importHeader(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::StringRef, swift::SourceLoc, bool, std::__1::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer, std::__1::default_delete<llvm::MemoryBuffer> >) + 985
8  swift                    0x0000000101605656 swift::ClangImporter::importBridgingHeader(llvm::StringRef, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceLoc, bool) + 502
9  swift                    0x00000001015f5c29 swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 601
10 swift                    0x000000010113a326 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 934
11 swift                    0x000000010113941d frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2781
12 swift                    0x0000000101134e3c main + 1932
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8a0d15ad start + 1
Stack dump:
```

I'm using cocoapods for package management and using swift + objc in the same project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding `Pods/**` to the `User Header Search Paths` build setting on my app target

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: That caused new error **file not found with <angled> include; user quoates instead**